# Is there a critical size for a bacteria colony forming?

Tags: bacteriology

I am a maths student doing a project based on modelling bacteria and phages. In one of my models the bacteria population reaches a population size of ~450 cells.

Would a colony of bacteria this size be at risk of completely dying out if there was an environmental change (e.g. pH or UV)? 
Also, is there such a thing as a critical colony size? e.g. if a colony of a certain type of bacteria falls below this critical size then the probability of a colony forming would be very low.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  What type of bacteria? How much of a change? What environment are they in currently?  And pH or UV is two questions; it would be best to [edit] down to just one to make the question answerable.  Thanks!

Comment: _Can you be more specific about what your goals are in your simulation?_ We would need to know a lot more about the kind of model you're talking about to know what the significance of a particular number of bacterial cells is. "Colonies" of bacteria are generally artificial and arise in the lab because we grow cells in isolation or near-isolation on nutrient plates under controlled conditions. Such cells are growing as fast as they can; it's not like they need a critical mass of cells to survive.